# Registering a MassTransit SagaStateMachine with RedisRepository in SimpleInjector - Multiple Constructors

Tags: .net, masstransit, simple-injector, automatonymous

I am able to register a MassTranst SagaStateMachine in a SimpleInjector container using the InMemoryRepository:

```
container.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
{
    // Unrelated registration code ommitted
    // ...

    cfg.AddSagaStateMachine<FormEvaluateStateMachine, FormEvaluateState>()
        .InMemoryRepository();
});
```

**container** being the SimpleInjector container.

If I change the line in there to:

cfg.AddSagaStateMachine<FormEvaluateStateMachine, FormEvaluateState>()
**.RedisRepository()**;

I get the following error from simple injector:

> For the container to be able to create RedisSagaRepositoryContextFactory it should have only one public constructor: it has 2. See https://simpleinjector.org/one-constructor for more information.

So somewhere its trying to register an implementation for RedisSagaRepositoryContextFactory which indeed has two constructors.

Is there an **elegant** way to solve this?  It looks like SimpleInjector offers a kludge to allow for multiple constructors but enabling that anti-pattern on a systemwide basis seems a little heavyhanded.

Is there a way to tell SimpleInjector to only do it for certain types?  I assume I want to use the constructor that takes ConnectionMultiplexer but I'm not certain.  I would have tagged my post with SimpleInjector but I don't have enough internet points.

Maybe there is a better way to specify the RedisRepository() so this doesn't happen?

I'm also in full framework so maybe not having Redis itself properly registered is my issue?

Comment: Seems like a bug in the MassTransit integration package.

Comment: Otherwise, try overriding the registration for RedisSagaRepositoryContextFactory with a custom one that use a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

It should be using the `ConnectionMultiplexer` constructor, seems like an issue with Simple Injector not being able to figure it out.

Seems like you can [specify a strategy](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-constructor-resolution-behavior) for constructor selection, and override the default behavior only for that type.